# Important Alien Message

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, no-computers, symbols

A strange alien transcript, alongside what is believed to be a partial key, was recovered the other day. Scientists aren't sure what the message might contain, but theories point to some sort of significant cultural data stored within...
[image: cipher]
[image: partial_key]

**Update:**
After thorough research, scientists have uncovered what is likely some sort of order to a subset of the alien glyphs. How exactly this information may be used is uncertain, but it is believed this may provide some order to the partial key that was recovered.
[image: Order]

### HINTS

> The key seems jumbled, and may become clearer if rearranged in some fashion...

> Order may be less important than you think.

> Solving this cipher is impossible unless you first *solve the key*.

> 16 squares, 16 boxes, 16 numbers. 4 symbols, 2 directions, 8 coordinates.

> Square the key, solve the numbers. Follow the directions, decode the cipher.

> Once correctly rearranged, the key will resemble a well known type of puzzle. The labels should help here.

> I bet you could solve this entire thing upside down

> Think of the cipher as a series of directions, in both directions.

> uk sued tokyo

> Look not where they are, but where they are facing

> [image: Partial Key with hints]

Comment: Do you have a transcription of the text in the first image (using, say, an arbitrary letter for each symbol)?

Comment: I do not have a transcription written up currently. If I need to, I can do so later, but the symbols should all be unique enough to be differentiated properly

Comment: Sure, they can be differentiated fairly easily - it's just a lot of work getting them into a more easily analyzable form.

Comment: V guvax guvf ybat grkg vf n fgevat bs onfr-fvkgrra qvtvgf ercerfragrq nf ovg fgevatf, gung obgu gur qbgf naq gur ybj-serdrapl flzobyf npg nf qvtvg frcnengbef, gung gur qbhoyr-qbg frdhrapr ercerfragf gur qvtvg mreb fvapr vg unf ab 1-ovgf orgjrra gur qbgf, naq gung gur ybj serdhrapl flzobyf ner fbzr xvaq bs pbageby punenpgre. V qba'g xabj jung V fubhyq cnl nggragvba gb arkg.

Comment: V guvax lbh ner sbphfvat gbb zhpu ba gur pvcure, naq abg rabhtu ba ubj gur xrl jbexf.

Comment: Gur xrl ybbxf yvxr fvkgrra haeryngrq fhofgvghgvbaf ba gur urk qvtvgf. Gung'f jurer gur vqrn pnzr sebz. Gur urnqvatf fhttrfg gubfr flzobyf gryy zr juvpu fhofgvghgvba gb hfr ng qvssrerag cbvagf va gur grkg.

Comment: _Square_ the key!? What does this refer to? Numbers!? Spoiler alert!

Comment: How should I tilt my head in order to read the vertical axis (horizontal line labels) in the key? On the right shoulder or on the left shoulder? Do I read BFC (tilt on left shoulder) or BGC (tilt on right shoulder?) Letter notations as defined by @codewarrior0 . Common sense would be "tilt on the left".

Comment: Also, the key reminds me strongly of Gray counters / encoders.

Comment: @virolino Perhaps it doesn't matter how you tilt your head :)

Comment: @ExecutionByFork: I am the stage of... filling in the blanks. I already made some mistakes. After a good night's sleep I will start again.. And then, I maybe I will find out that tilting might not be important :)

Comment: @ExecutionByFork: are you sure that there is a unique solution to the key? I got stuck, and I verified with an online solver if  made a mistake, and the solver generated multiple solutions. Suggestions? :) I guess that not any key can decode the original message.

Comment: What did you use? When I made this I verified with an online solver and it gave me one solution

Comment: @virolino I think you made a transcription error somewhere. I just checked again, and verified with a separate tool. There is only one solution to the key

Comment: @ExecutionByFork: I verified already several times before commenting and after. Only after you answered, and I verified again, I found out that I read dot-dot-line-line in the first box as dot-dot-line. Now i solve it again. I lost the count of restarts :))

Comment: I haven't seen any comments or activity on here for a while. Is anyone trying to solve this? Where are people stuck? Knowing this I might be able to provide better hints.

Comment: Wait... did UK really sue Tokyo?

Comment: That clue is a very small puzzle

Comment: 11 hints already. Must be very important!

Comment: @ExecutionByFork Sudoku to key?

Comment: Yes but reverse the order of those words

Comment: @ExecutionByFork Key to Sudoku!? Key to Sudoku, that shall be right!

Comment: Since the key is broken up into pieces, there are 600-odd ways to reassemble them and still get a valid Sudoku. Are they all cryptographically equivalent?

Comment: @codewarrior0 If I understand what you're saying, I think you are missing a key piece of information used to determine how the key is reassembled. Hint #4 and #6 may help. There is only one valid sudoku

Comment: Uh-oh. I can permute the rows and columns of any valid sudoku in box-aligned groups of four and obtain another valid sudoku. I found the information that tells me which boxes are in the same row and which are in the same column, but nothing about what the original order was.

Comment: Hmmm... It took me a bit to understand what you meant, but I see now... and I definitely overlooked this during puzzle creation lol. I have updated the question to provide an order for you, which should resolve the problem. My bad on that.

Answer (score 10):

Not an answer.

Alphabetic transcription of alien writing:

```
QBADFAHGCAEBACDABEA
FIJCHAEGADFAIEAAHA
DGBACAFEILIAGADBAAA
AAAFCEADHAGBNEAIFAB
HDGAIEFAGCHAFADMEF
AHCABIADACHEGADBAO
AHDACFIEAHDBAGEIAH
FADCKFEABIAHCADGA
BFEAIADHAAGCJDAHB
FAGIACHAIAEADAEFAGA
HBADMAEIFCABHAIACA
DABHAEGCAPIAABEAFA
DCGAAHQGBAEIAHCABA
FCDAEBGAIOFAHEABD
IACHAIAGBAELAFBEAA
HGAFCADAIPAHGCADBA
IFCAEBAHAGDAIEAFC
KIGCAEADFABACEAGH
AIFAGADBHN
```

I've tried to use a system for the transcription key. The most common symbol is assigned to `A`, and the pairs `BC`, `DE`, `FG`, and `HI` are symbols that are rotations of each other.

[image]

Letter frequency:

```
108  27   26   27   28   25   24   27   25   
 A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I  

 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2 
 J    K    L    M    N    O    P    Q

Total: 333
```

The only letter that follows itself is `A`. There is no `BB`, or `CC`, or any double letter in the text other than `AA`.

Letter contacts of the nine most frequent letters. Each letter contacts `A` more frequently than it contacts every other letter.

[image]

The longest repetition is `IACHAIA`. This is expected by chance for one out of three messages of this kind. There are 8 other five-letter repetitions, also barely allowed by chance.

Comment: I'm 80% sure A is a space-separator, and AA is a full stop, so that AAAAAA is an ellipsis.

Comment: 108 word separators and full stops out of 333 letters? That gives an average word length of about 2.27. I'm not sure that's right. If A is instead a *letter separator*, then there is a letter represented by 6 consecutive symbols; there are only 99 letters in the plaintext; and the most frequent "letter" is `D` occuring four times. So I doubt A is either kind of separator.

Comment: Thank you for the transcription! I don't think it's likely that it's simply encoded English - presumably the diagram below with the Mayan numerals is important too.

Comment: Without the dots, which may be space separators or something, there are only 16 unique characters. There are also exactly 16 grids/boxes in the "partial key."

Comment: The way eight of the 16 unique symbols each only occur twice, and they are also found heading the grids in the "partial key" makes me think those symbols control the way the cipher works, maybe switching from one grid to another.

Comment: There's some useful information here, and if you've done all this by hand, I'm impressed; but i suspect you've missed the [tag:no-computers] tag on the question.

Comment: Nothing I've done could not have been done on graph paper and tracing paper by a professional codebreaker in the 1920s; and they would have done all of the above as a matter of course.

Comment: The way I see it, the analysis codewarrior has done is fine. Using a computer to count symbol frequency and plot relationships is not a big deal. These are monotonous tasks you could do by hand, and it is simply a time saver. What I intended with the no-computers tag was to disallow, say, running parts or all of the puzzle through automated solving tools to arrive at an answer. Things where a computer would take part of the "computational" load or provide answers that a solver would otherwise need to deduce.

Comment: @ExecutionByFork fair enough. It's your question so your call on what is acceptable.

Comment: @codewarrior And not only that, the symbols heading the grids fit into two distinct categories: each heading is one of {J,N,O,P} and one of {K,L,M,Q} (in some order), with all sixteen combinations represented. And not only *that*, those symbols in the message alternate between the two sets, and if you use the 'swapping' interpretation, 15 out of the 16 possible combinations are used. (You get the sixteenth if you 'wrap around' in the message, but there are no invertible characters at the end.)

Comment: Way ahead of you. Next, split up the message into groups using `AJKLMNOPQ` as delimiters, and notice that no group is longer than four letters, *and* that each group never contains more than one of each of the pairs in `BC DE FG HI`. Yet, after splitting the message into these groups and replacing C with B, E with D, etc... the result is not monoalphabetic, which is why I think the eight low-frequency symbols are control symbols that change the substitution.

Comment: I don't think it's a straight substitution cipher - at least, not that directly, and especially not throwing away orientation information. After all, we still need to actually use the 4x4 grids! And the 'coordinate markings' on the 4x4s suggest that orientation is important, and imply an asymmetrical role for two of the pairs in `BC DE FG HI`.

Comment: Oh! I think I might've come across an idea... let me see if it works out. (It still wouldn't explain the 'extra' grid from wrapping around, and why it doesn't have any characters for itself, though...)

Comment: The reason I don't think orientation is important is because if you consider only the letters `BC` in the order they appear in the text, they spell out a repeating `BCBCBCBC` sequence, only repeating a `BB` or a `CC` when there is a low-frequency symbol between them (and even then only rarely). Likewise for all of `DE FG HI`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that as well! I think they still convey useful information, though - that repeating pattern is important to how this works.

Comment: I've transcribed and translated the grids and put them in the order suggested by the low-frequency symbols. Grids whose headings are reversed from the given order have the actual heading in parentheses. I can't find any obvious patterns in the way the grid cells are filled. https://pastebin.com/M3U1QD5D

Comment: And remember... solving the cipher is impossible unless you first **solve the key** :)

Comment: Yeah, it has to be one of those grid deduction things where different parts of the grid only contain unique elements. I was hoping I could solve it without the key. Oh well.

Comment: @codewarrior0 16 squares. 16 boxes. 16 numbers. 16 is such a lucky number to use.

Comment: Square the key, solve the numbers. Follow the directions, decode the cipher.

Comment: I appreciate the enthusiasm, but I don't think we need the hints repeated in the comments. They're in the puzzle post already :)

Comment: I was too excited. :)

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer

> The key is a bunch of fragments of a 16x16 sudoku. The glyphs above the each subgrid can help: each glyph appears only in one column or in only one row. As a sudoku can be permuted by rows or by columns of subgrids without becoming invalid, a recent update gave the ordering of the rows and columns by ordering the glyphs they correspond to. Here is the resulting completed sudoku. Orange boxes are the ones added in a hint by the author, green ones are completed by solving the assembled sudoku. [image]

From there I have only guesses

> There are 2 types of glyphs. Those above the subgrids (in pairs) are probably those called "coordinates" because there are 8 of those. The "4 symbols, 2 directions" are probably the small glyphs on the edges of the subgrids. There are 4 glyphs, each appearing in two orientations.

> Now for decoding the message. In each series of glyphs separated by a dot, there is only one coordinate, but there may be 0, 1 or several symbols. My guess is that these are some sort of instructions to navigate the sudoku grid and find numbers.

> I don't really understand what would be the meaning of the symbols' orientation. In fact, 2 symbols are displayed on the subgrids with only one orientation. The fact that there are 8 possible versions of the symbols may correspond to the 8 adjacent tiles of a square (accounting for tiles on the diagonals). But I don't see how that matches the picture of the subgrids.